# Copy table from remote sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, replication

Is there any way to copy data from one remote sqlite database to another? I have file replication done across two servers; however, some changes are recorded in an sqlite database local to each server. To get my file replication to work correctly, I need to copy the contents of one table and enter them into the table on the opposite system. I understand that sqlite databases are not meant for remote access; but is there any way to do what I need? I suppose I could write the contents of the table to a file, copy that file, then add the contents to the other database. This doesn't seem like the best option though, so I'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the other database file, you can [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) it:

```
ATTACH '/some/where/else/other.db' AS remote;
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM remote.MyTable;
```